# Ubuntu 17 dock file drag

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, dock, drag-and-drop, ubuntu-dock

In Ubuntu 16, I was able to drag files to apps in the dock, but in Ubuntu 17.10, that's not working. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 Unity? Or Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome? Big difference.

Comment: @user535733 Gnome

Comment: DnD of files on launcher icons is not supported in gnome-shell. You could go back to unity if desired or try adding a different dock like docky or plank (plank is xorg only

Comment: @doug please add this as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DnD of files on icons in gnome-shells dock to open app dropped on is not a supported feature.

Even the Dash to Dock extension creator notes this, referenced - https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/578

Third party docks should work as expected, 2 examples are  Docky & Plank. Note that plank is xorg only, no wayland support yet. (or ever?

Another path is to install unity & use it instead. Though for best performance of unity one should also switch back to lightdm & remove gdm3, gnome-shell, ect. Note that unity is also xorg only.